# Wordpress/Elementor Popup Issue

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have created a live website using Wordpress and Elementor. In the website I have a navigation menu with 8 sub menus. In one of the menus, I have added a popup that has another 7-8 sub menus. Some of those sub menus have one more popup that contains buttons with links that takes me to another page in my website. Now, when I click on any of the buttons, the parent popup closes automatically but the child popup which contains the buttons does not close unless and until the new page is loaded via the button's link click. Since the new page to be loaded takes a bit time, I can clearly see the child popup on the screen after the button is clicked. Any help on how to resolve this would mean a lot!

I have attached an image below for clear explanation of the issue

[image]

I have tried to apply custom HTML but I can't seem to make it work correctly. Any other method or even a method using custom HTML would be appreciated